# collate all SharePoint items for each person and email the person once

Tags: power-automate

I am trying to create a work flow in which an email is sent weekly to an employee, the flow pulls from a SharePoint List and generates a table for that employee for every item that is assigned to them.  I have the following flow built and it runs just fine except the table produces nothing.  I think the gap is in my filter array step but I am not certain.  New to powerautomate so please bear with me.

[image: Get Items]

The LH001e item is a People field in my list, these are the individuals that will be receiving an email with the table of items assigned to them.

[image: Select]

Submitters is a Compose that uses union to remove any duplicate entries from the Select. This will give me unique list of LH001e values (This may also be a gap but I don't know).

[image: Submitters]

[image: Filter Array, Create HTML Table]
This is what I used in the Filter Array, trying to associate my submitters list to the table.
items('Apply_to_each')?['DisplayName']

[image: Send Email]

I may have missed sharing something but that is the entire flow as I have it presently built.

This is what I am getting in my email when I should have 3 items included.
[image: Blank email]

Here is my list.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your LH001eSubmittedBy field is a person or group type of field I would suggest to use the Email below in the Select Map field:

```
item()?['LH001eSubmittedBy/EMail']
```

In addition to that I would also use

```
item()?['LH001eSubmittedBy/EMail'] is equal to item()
```

Instead of item()?['LH001eSubmittedBy'] is equal to items('Apply_to_each')?['DisplayName'] in the Filter Array criteria.

Comment: So I changed the expressions you mentioned.  I am getting an error in the Send Email step.

Comment: InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Send_an_email_(V2)' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language expression 'item()?['LH001eSubmittedBy/EMail']' cannot be evaluated because property 'LH001eSubmittedBy/EMail' cannot be selected. Property selection is not supported on values of type 'String'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.

Comment: Also doesn't look like the data was pulled still for the HTML table.

Comment: That Send an Email (v2) action is within the loop, correct? If that is the case you can use `item()` for the To field.

Comment: Ok, it sent the email but I am still getting a blank table.  Has my headers but I have 3 items that should be populating in the table.

Comment: Something is wrong with my Filter Array step.  I can see the inputs but it doesn't produce any outputs.